# set max input using looping compact in blade script laravel

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to set max number from selected item. data max number from controller compact.

after i use select2 and datatables its cannot working. maybe I accidentally deleted an asset or something.

```
function max() {
  var item_selected = document.getElementById("select").value;
  var item= {!! json_encode($item->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
  //when i see the source
  //var item= [{"id":1,"owned":1},{"id":2,"owned":10},{"id":3,"owned":12}];


  for (i = 0; i<=item.length; i++){
  //when i use console.log
  //it still show id but the error moves to this with same error.
  //console.log(item[i].id)
    if (item[i].id==item_selected)
    {
            var input = document.getElementById("number");
            input.setAttribute("max",item[i].owned);
    }
  }
}
```

the error part is if (item[i].id==item_selected)
and it said Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i<=owned.length; i++)
```

this line should be

```
for (i = 0; i<=item.length; i++)
```

side note: you can use a localized variable to avoid inlining blade within your javascript

Comment: after i change it still show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: `<=` should be `<`

Comment: @Tim I guess that doesn't matter. I change to < and still

Comment: Thats strange. `for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++)` is the correct way to loop over an array. And the error means that some `item[i]` is undefined. Which simply cannot happen this way (I think...). Can you check if you really used `<` and not some older cached version of your code?